# Can't run any python commands from cmd

Tags: python, cmd, syntax

So i've been getting this error for a while, i can't run any command from cmd. It seems python entrepeneur is working but for some reason i get basic syntax error for simple commands:
[line 4 running entrepreneur, line 7 'dir' working, line 9 cant cd to desktop, line 14 can't open a file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82Hdg.png)

I really dont know what to try, maybe reinstall the entrepreneur, maybe my python isn't on the same directory as the system (??? dont even know if this is a thing)

Comment: Please don't post images of code, errors, logs, or other text; see [ask]. That said, you try to shell commands in Python. Do your `cd` before calling `py`. Or don't call `py` at all, if you want to run `spdump.py`. Your commands probably work on a shell, but not in the Python interpreter.

Comment: Once you are in the Python interpreter (shown by `>>>` as your prompt), whatever you type is handled by the Python interpreter, not by CMD. So for example `cd desktop` won't work, because `cd` is a CMD command, not Python.

Answer (score 1):

In python, you can use os.system(command) to call system commands. The error you are seeing is the lack of instructions in the language itself, for the simple reason that it is a programming language and not a console.

For example:

```
import os
os.system("dir")
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system